# How can I wrap qrsh?

Tags: sungridengine

I'm trying to write a wrapper for qrsh, the Oracle Grid Engine equivalent to rsh, and am having trouble identifying the command given to it. Consider the following example:

```
qrsh -cwd -V -now n -b y -N cvs -verbose -q some.q -p -98 cvs -Q log -N -S -d2012-04-09 14:02:08 GMT<2012-04-11 21:53:41 GMT -b
```

The command in this case starts from cvs. My wrapper needs to be general purpose so I can't look specifically for cvs. Any ideas on how to identify it? One thought is to look for executable commands starting from the end backwards, which will work in this case but won't be robust as "cvs" could appear in an option to itself. The only robust option that I can come up with is to fully implement the qrsh option parser but I'm not thrilled about it since it will need to be updated with qrsh updates and is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set QRSH_WRAPPER to echo and run qrsh once. However, this then requires two jobs to be issued instead of one, adding latency and wasting a slot.